# Restore or remove the Linux Kernel Module from sysfs

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I recently coded a LKM which has the ability to hide itself. All works just fine when I hide the module but when I restore it and look at it in the lsmod the value of the `Used By` column suddenly is -2

```
Module                  Size  Used by
my_module                13324  -2 
vboxsf                   43798  1 
dm_crypt                 23177  0 
nfsd                    284396  2 
auth_rpcgss              59309  1 nfsd
nfs_acl                  12837  1 nfsd
nfs                     240815  0
```

and when I remove it i get the error saying `rmmod: ERROR: Module my_module is builtin.` I know that it is a refcount for the `kobject` associated with the module and the module can only be removed when it is `0`. I am almost certain that it happens because when I hide the module I delete all of its files in the `/sys/modules`.(`holders`, `parameters`, `sections`, `srcversion` etc.). Can someone help me with the remove operation or restore the files back?(I don't get any errors in the `dmesg`)

Here is the code:
`

```
void module_hide(void) {
    if(module_hidden) //is hidden
            return;
    module_prev = THIS_MODULE->list.prev;
    kobject_prev = &THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj;
    kobject_parent_prev = THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj.parent;

    sect_attrs_bkp = THIS_MODULE->sect_attrs;
    notes_attrs_bkp = THIS_MODULE->notes_attrs;

    list_del(&THIS_MODULE->list);             //remove from procfs
    //kobject_del(THIS_MODULE->holders_dir);
    kobject_del(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj);    //remove from sysfs

    THIS_MODULE->sect_attrs = NULL;
    THIS_MODULE->notes_attrs = NULL;
    module_hidden = (unsigned int)0x1;
}
void module_show(void) {
    int result, result2;
    if(!module_hidden) //is not hidden
            return;
    list_add(&THIS_MODULE->list, module_prev); //add to procfs

    result = kobject_add(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj, kobject_parent_prev, "my_module");     //add the module to sysfs
    if(result<0) {
            printk(KERN_ALERT "Error to restore the old kobject\n");
    }
    result2 = kobject_add(THIS_MODULE->holders_dir, &THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj, "holders"); //add the holders dir to the module folder
    if(!THIS_MODULE->holders_dir) {
            printk(KERN_ALERT "Error to restore the old holders_dir\n");
    }
    THIS_MODULE->sect_attrs = sect_attrs_bkp;
    THIS_MODULE->notes_attrs = notes_attrs_bkp;
    //kobject_get(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj);
    //tried using THIS_MODULE->refcnt = 0; and kobject_get(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kob) with no luck
    module_hidden = (unsigned int)0x0;
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: This is the only part that is related to hiding/showing the module. I can add the whole code but I don't think that would be helpful

Comment: I hooked the `kill` syscall. By sending signals I hide/unhide this module

Comment: Yes. The only problem occurs after I unhide it again which I believe cannot be done since there are no entries in the `/sys/module/my_module`

Comment: It's Ok :) kobject_parent_prev is a `kobject *` which holds the pointer to the parent of the kobject. I use it to store the kobject's parent to have a  valid pointer pointing to the parent when I unhide it again. The "deleting from list"(list_add & list_del) part is actually related to procfs which works fine. Only problem occurs with sysfs and kobjects

Comment: I am thinking use some other method to hide in sysfs.

Answer (score 1):

Using kobject_add will only add the directory as you already know, while using kobject_dell will remove the direcotry and all subdirectories.
Hence as you mention you need to add all of the subdires needed.

To understand what is the way of adding the subdirs, you read the source code of sys_init_module carefully at [module.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/module.c) or read [kobject_del](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/kobject.c#L609)->[sys_remove_dir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/sysfs/dir.c#L80) 
which remove all attributes(files) and subdirs when clear recursively `kobj->kernfs_nodes`.

Thus, you need create the struct recursivly with all his attrs using the functions

- `sysfs_add_file_mode_ns`
- `sysfs_create_dir_ns`

or:

- `__kernfs_create_file`
- `kernfs_create_empty_dir`

for example to add the sections file use the follwoing line:

`sysfs_create_group(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj, &sect_attrs_bkp->grp))`

You need you change more values in order  to fix the problem but to restore the directories this will be enough.

But other solution and perherp easier one would be just to make you module directory unvisible by hijacking getdents_t and getdents64_t as done at [Diamorphine](https://github.com/m0nad/Diamorphine).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
static void populate_sysfs(void)
{
    int i;
    THIS_MODULE->holders_dir=kobject_create_and_add("holders",&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj);
    for (i=0;(THIS_MODULE->modinfo_attrs[i].attr.name) != NULL;i++){
      if (sysfs_create_file(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj,&THIS_MODULE->modinfo_attrs[i].attr)!=0)
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could restore all of the files and sub-directories, but still rmmod is stuck when trying to unload the module, working on a fix but might try another way like @TomerSamara Said.

Here's how I recovered it:

```
static void show_mod(void) {
    static int i;
    // add to the modules linked list the current module after the one it already had been attached
    list_add(&THIS_MODULE->list, prev_module);
    // add the kobjects to sysfs again
    kobject_add(kobject_prev, kobject_parent_prev, mod_fmt);
    THIS_MODULE->holders_dir = kobject_create_and_add("holders", &THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj);
    for (i=0;(THIS_MODULE->modinfo_attrs[i].attr.name) != NULL;i++){

        pr_info("Creating %s\n", THIS_MODULE->modinfo_attrs[i].attr.name);

        if (sysfs_create_file(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj,&THIS_MODULE->modinfo_attrs[i].attr)!=0)

        pr_err("couldn't create %s\n", THIS_MODULE->modinfo_attrs[i].attr.name);

    }
    notes_attrs_prev->dir = kobject_create_and_add("notes", &THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj);
    for (i=0; i < notes_attrs_prev->notes; i++){
        sysfs_create_bin_file(notes_attrs_prev->dir,
                  &notes_attrs_prev->attrs[i]);
    }
    sysfs_create_group(&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj, &sect_attrs_prev->grp);
    THIS_MODULE->notes_attrs = notes_attrs_prev;
    THIS_MODULE->sect_attrs = sect_attrs_prev;
}
```